# How to link a slot in the code with a QWidget in mainwindow

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qlcdnumber

I am a beginner with signal & slots in QtCreator.

I would like to know how to connect a signal declared in mainwindow code in a Qwidget LCDNumber include in the mainwindow.

[image]

Because even if my ManWindow signal is diclared correctly (I guess)

[image]

I can't configure the connection between MainWindow signal and LDCNumber Display(int) SLOT it in design mode :

[image]

Would you know how to code the connection of MainWindow SIGNAL declared in MinWindow's Class and LCDNumber include in Mainwindow's SLOT, please?

Here are all the propeties of QLCDNumber class :

[image]

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: at first, I want to ask you never to use QT instead of Qt.
QT==> QuickTime
Qt==> c++ framework
in QtCreator there is now no way to connect user defined signal to user defined slot. but you can connect them in c++ code by connect method.
something like this :
connect(widgetA, SIGNAL(signal()), widgetB, SLOT(slot());

Comment: Ok, Qt, got it.
I tried a code like 
`connect(widgetA, SIGNAL(signal()), widgetB, SLOT(slot());` but I have no Widget A to connect only a QObject in my C++ code. I just wanna link my C++ code to the "widget B" LCDNumber widget in the MainWindow. What should I write instead of `widgetB, SLOT(slot())` please?

Comment: I recommend that you read the official document

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

in your case you can write the below code :
if QMainview object named mainView and LCDNumber named  lcd


connect(mainView, SIGNAL(Vxx_cost_disp_update(int)), lcd, SLOT(on_Vxx_cost_disp_update(int)));

Comment: Hello Sajad, thanks for sharing the signals & slots topic. I already read it. I added the propeties of my LCD object in my post above and I tried to code the connection as you suggested :
    `connect(&Vxx_cost_disp,SIGNAL(TransmitConnectorValue(int)),this,SLOT(on_Vxx_cost_disp_updated(int)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(Vxx_cost_disp_update(int)), &lcdNumber, SLOT(display(int)));`
But it still say that "lcdNumber" is not declared in that scope. 
(I also tried to replace "this" by "MainWindow" as you suggested and "&ldcNumber" by "&QLCDNumber")

Comment: @NicolasBrx , use new Signal Slot syntax, it gives better compilet time warnings: https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Comment: Thanks Roman! 
I tried to decladre the connection the new may but "lcdNumber" is not recognized by connect function...
`connect(Vxx_cost_disp,&MainWindowSignal::TransmitConnectorValue(int),lcdNumber,&QLCDNumber::display(int));`
(I posed my QLCDNumber object properties above)

Comment: can you share your project or a simple project that demonstrates your problem?

note: when any *.ui file send to UIC(what happened in your case) ,a new file was generated that contains all new widgets that inserted in UI file and his name is like ui_classname.
finally added all them to base class and declare a ui variable .you have to add "ui->" before call widget.some things like this ==>  "ui->lcdnumber"

Comment: https://estaca-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/nicolas_bierinx_estaca_eu/EcMJ4ZOkTxRHi0a9xeyP_gIB2gfCO4SOV5HX7ixARW7-Cw?e=Hfu6UZ
Here is a link to my OneDrive.
By running the programme you should have a QDebug display each second. Then you will find the issue commented on line 46 of Mainwindow.cpp and it's description on line 43 to 45. 
This code is compiled on a Raspberry Pi 3B+.